# How to read block of memory with java

Tags: java

Is it possible to read values of a block from "memory or file" with java?

For example values of 32bit*8bit blocks.

I tried to use Unsafe but I wasn't successful

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Comment: What do you mean by a "block"?

Comment: And by "memory or file"?